# Find max values for each 5 rows in pd.DateFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some marketing data with 1-minute interval. 
As a sample of csv-table,  each row represents max values for each minute:

```
time    ch1     ch2 ch3 ch4      
20:03   1754    539 149 1337     
20:04   2073    576 160 1448     
20:05   2246    599 176 1515     
20:06   2246    637 176 1531     
20:07   2457    651 183 1549     
20:08   2564    677 184 1655     
20:09   2624    712 191 1699     
20:10   2742    717 194 1672     
20:11   2788    714 199 1675     
20:12   2792    693 186 1680     
20:13   2914    708 188 1672     
20:14   3067    715 194 1685     
20:15   3067    725 196 1682
```

additionally, I need to find max values for each 5 minute. So I need to find max for every 5 rows (or less - if there are no more rows remained) of each columns and insert it to new 5-minute row.

What I looking to recieve (as example):

each new row has to represent max value for  5

```
time    ch1     ch2 ch3 ch4     
20:03   2564    677 184 1655     
20:08   2914    717 199 1699     
20:13   3067    725 196 1685
```

I honestly have searched but no result.

Is there in Python some elegant solution for my task?
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5)
g.max().assign(time=g.time.first())

    time   ch1  ch2  ch3   ch4   ch5
0  20:03  2457  651  183  1549  4840
1  20:08  2792  717  199  1699  5376
2  20:13  3067  725  196  1685  5670
```

Answer (score 4):

By using your input :

```
df['group']=df.index//5
target=df.groupby('group').agg(max)
target['time']=df.groupby('group').time.agg(min)

Out[511]: 
        time   ch1  ch2  ch3   ch4   ch5
group                                   
0      20:03  2457  651  183  1549  4840
1      20:08  2792  717  199  1699  5376
2      20:13  3067  725  196  1685  5670
```

Answer (score 3):

Im going to assume that you did not convert your values to `datetime` since you specified this is a csv table of data, so I will convert the index to `datetime`.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%H:%M')
```

Now that the index is of `datetime` format we can use `resample` to group by 5 minute intervals. Note: I will set the base to 3 here since that is how you wanted it formatted, however I think in the long run you may be better suited leaving it at 0. So to group the data just run

```
df.resample('5T',base=3).max().drop('time',1)
```

To dynamically set the base to the first minute value use

```
df.resample('5T',base=int(df.time.values[0][-1:])).max().drop('time',1)
```

Yields

```
                      ch1  ch2  ch3   ch4
time
2017-09-20 20:03:00  2457  651  183  1549
2017-09-20 20:08:00  2792  717  199  1699
2017-09-20 20:13:00  3067  725  196  1685
```

If you dont want the date in the index just run

```
df.index = df.index.time
```

However, you need the date included to resample

```
           ch1  ch2  ch3   ch4
20:03:00  2457  651  183  1549
20:08:00  2792  717  199  1699
20:13:00  3067  725  196  1685
```

Comment: Thanks! But in the dataset there are several days (15.09, 16.09, 17.09). Do you now, how to set different days in dateframe? (cause it would be .xls format, not only .csv).

Comment: Can you update your sample to include dates? If it is just a column of dates, you can combine the column and make it a datetime object